# Bash menus from external file

Tags: arrays, bash, macos

Don't know where to ask for help so trying here.
I'm creating a bash menu script with some operations and reading lots of bash tutorials but think my brain is starting to melt with all different syntax and ways to do it, can't fully wrap my head around bash/sh. End script will run on OSX for an art team.

#### **What this is**

A script to upload/download files with rsync.
The script that will grab latest 'config/menu' from remote server. That file **menu.txt** will create an menu that lists project and when selected you get the option to download / upload.

#### **Issue**

Where I'm stuck is how to handle arrays to menus. Tried 2d arrays with no luck so now it's split into 3 arrays to hold the values I need. However when trying to display the menus I can't get it to work correctly. Look at the bottom for how to test, what is shows and what it should show.

#### **more info: create_menus function**

This function parse the menu.txt to build an array that is used when showing a menu,

```
Project Title5, source1dir, destination1dir
Project Title6, source2dir, destination2dir
Project Title7, source3dir, destination3dir
```

Instead of gettin selection 1 'Project Title5' a menu will display

```
1) Project
2) Title5Project
3) Title6Project
4) Title7Quit
```

Script:

```
function create_menus() {
    #operations for project
    MENU_OPERATIONS=(
      "Get latest from remote"
      "Show changes from remote"
      "Send latest from me to remote"
      "Show changes from me to remote"
      "Return to main menu"
  )
    #projects to choose from, load from textfile
    declare -a t; declare -a s; declare -a d;
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        IFS=',' read -ra obj <<< "$line"
        #TODO 2d array nicer than 3 arrays!
        eval "t+=\"${obj[0]}\""
        eval "s+=\"${obj[1]}\""
        eval "d+=\"${obj[2]}\""
    done <$FILE_MENU
    t+="Quit" #add quit
    MENU_MAIN=($t)
    PROJECT_SOURCE=($s)
    PROJECT_TARGET=($d)
}
```

then to show the main menu **main_menu "${MENU_MAIN[@]}"**

```
function main_menu
{
    #clear
    #header
    PS3="Select project: "
    select option; do # in "$@" is the default
        if [ "$REPLY" -eq "$#" ];
        then
            echo "Exiting..."
            break;
        elif [ 1 -le "$REPLY" ] && [ "$REPLY" -le $(($#-1)) ];
        then
            # $REPLY = index
            # $option = text
            echo "You selected $option which is option $REPLY"
            SELETED_PROJECT_TITLE=${MENU_MAIN[$REPLY]}
            SELETED_PROJECT_SOURCE=${PROJECT_SOURCE[$REPLY]}
            SELETED_PROJECT_TARGET=${PROJECT_TARGET[$REPLY]}
            echo "Sel title $SELETED_PROJECT_TITLE"
            echo "Sel source $SELETED_PROJECT_SOURCE"
            echo "Sel target $SELETED_PROJECT_TARGET"
            project_menu "${MENU_OPERATIONS[@]}" "$SELETED_PROJECT_TITLE" "$SELETED_PROJECT_SOURCE" "$SELETED_PROJECT_TARGET"
            break;
        else
            echo "Incorrect Input: Select a number 1-$#"
        fi
    done
}
```

Here's full code
https://github.com/fbacker/BigFileProjectsSync/blob/master/app.sh

**ADDED MORE DESCRIPTION**

To test:

```
git clone https://github.com/fbacker/BigFileProjectsSync.git
cd BigFileProjectsSync/
./app.sh
```

What happens:

```
Shows a menu with options:
1) Project
2) Title5Project
3) Title6Project
4) Title7Quit
```

Should happen:

```
Shows a menu with options:
1) Project Title5
2) Project Title6
3) Project Title7
4) Quit
```

app.sh > function create_menus() > This should create a menu based on the menu.txt file.

menu.txt one line is a project: first value is project name, second value is source directory and third is target directory.

Comment: "*it isn't formated in a way that works*" - could you please show the format that you need?

Comment: You don't need `eval` to append to the arrays.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your `create_menus()` function, which should do the trick:

```
function create_menus() {

    #operations for project
    # MENU_OPERATIONS=( # ... OMITTED FOR BREVITY

    #projects to choose from
    local -a titles sources destinations
    local title source destination
    while IFS='|' read -r title source destination; do
        titles+=( "$title" )
        sources+=( "$source" )
        destinations+=( "$destination" )
    done < <(sed 's/, /|/g' "$FILE_MENU")

    # Copy to global arrays
    MENU_MAIN+=( "${titles[@]}" )
    PROJECT_SOURCE+=( "${sources[@]}" )
    PROJECT_TARGET+=( "${destinations[@]}" )

    MENU_MAIN+=( "Quit" ) #add quit
}
```

There were 2 crucial problems with your approach (I'll assume an array variable `$arr` below):

- In order **to append a new element to an array, the new element must *itself* be specified as an array too; i.e., it must be enclosed in `(...)`**:

  - `arr+=( "$newElement" )` - OK: value is appended as new element
  - `arr+=$newElement` - BROKEN: *String-appends* the value of `$newElement` to `$arr`'s *first element*(!), without adding a new one.

    - `arr=( 1 2 ); arr+=3; declare -p arr` -> `declare -a arr='([0]="13" [1]="2")'`
- You **can't copy a whole array with `arrCopy=( $arr )`** - all that does is to create a single-item array containing only `$arr`'s *first* element. To refer to an array *as a whole*, you must use **`"${arr[@]}"`** (enclosing in `"..."` ensures that no word-splitting is applied):

  - `arrCopy=( "${arr[@]}" )` - OK
  - `arrCopy=( $arr )` - BROKEN - only copies 1st element

Also note that it's better not to use all-uppercase shell-variable names in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

---

Comment: Yaay, superthanks, not just for showing how it's done but the really well explained example.

Comment: For the interested parties I've updated the git and printing menus a little prettier.

Comment: @roady: My pleasure. Your question (and your code) are clearly crafted with care, but I think you'd have gotten help sooner if you had whittled down your question to an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - short, self-contained code that readers can easily copy and paste to verify the symptom.